# What properties does $A\to B$ satisfy under 1-1 correspondence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

A 1-1 correspondence between two sets $A$ and $B$ is a function $f\colon A \to B$ **satisfying what properties?**

I do know that we say that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, and we write $A \sim B$ iff they can be put into 1-1 correspondence. This is really an equivalence relation: $A \sim A$

If $A\sim B$ then $B \sim A$  $\sim$ is symmetric.
If $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$ then $A\sim C$  $\sim$ is transitive

I guess I am having trouble interpreting what the the initial question is asking?

I am trying to do this so I can prove that $|A| \leq |A|$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that $A\sim A$, all you have to do is find a function from $A$ to itself which is both injective and surjective.

For example, the identity function defined by $f(a)=a$.

Answer (score 0):

A one to one correspondence indicates that there is a map $f: A\to B$ that is onto, so that for every $b\in B$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$, and also one to one, meaning that the $a\in A$ such that $f(a) =b$ is unique.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you and i understand that. For diagnolization to work, this has to be true. But, what properties does this satisfy? (this is the part i did not understand)

Comment: When you say properties, I am not sure what you mean precisely. I think of one to one correspondences (or bijections) as set theoretic isomorphisms. Thus, any purely set theoretic properties of the two sets agree. For example, $|A| = |B|$.

Comment: I guess that is what i am confused about since all the question said was  "A 1-1 correspondence between two sets A  and B  is a function f:A→B  satisfying what properties?"

Comment: I think that the question is just looking for the two defining properties I mentioned. It is an oddly worded question, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

A 1-1 correspondence is another word for bijective. Thus, it is one-one and onto. A one-one function is a mapping such that f(x1) = f(x2) if and only if x1 = x2. An onto mapping is a mapping such that every element is mapped over. So suppose we have f = x + 1 and our set is [1,2,3,4]. Then our new set would be [2,3,4,5] so we see that this is a 1-1 corresondence.